# Match regex string not between 2 strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find jQuery strings that not properly wrapped in `$(document).ready(` or `$(function()`.

So it would match this:

```
console.log('something');
$('button').trigger('click');
$('div').css('color','red');
console.log('something else');
```

but it would not match this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // More js here
  $('label').trigger('click');
  $('div.something').text('hello');
  // more js here
});
```

or this

```
$(function(){
  $('.test').append('<div>taco</div>');
});
```

I've tried doing something this like:

```
(?=\$\(document)[\s\S]*\$\([\s\S]*\}\)
```

But it did sort of the opposite of what I wanted... Not sure how todo the inverse...

Comment: Not sure if (one single) regex (on its own) is the easiest tool for this job...

Comment: Oh I didn't even think about that but I suppose I could search for any jQuery and then check to see if it does NOT contain $(document) or $(function .... That is actually the way to go I think. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: What is your end goal in doing this? What is the context?

Comment: Need to search through hundreds for JavaScript files and find any that have jQuery that is not properly wrapped in `$(document)` or `$(function()`. Sorry I thought that was clear what I was trying to do in the question...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you would do this using one RegEx, but you're already (close to) half way to being able to do it using two.

First, find any occurrences of the blocks you would like to exclude, and replace them with an empty string.

I would use the following RegEx:

([RegEx101 Test Case](https://regex101.com/r/dO7qR7/7))

```
/(?:\$|jQuery)\((?:document\)\.ready\()?function.*?\(\){(?:[^{]|{[^]*}\);?)+}\);?/gi
```

[image]

Let's break that down:

- `(?:\$|jQuery)` looks for "$" or "jQuery",
- `\(` looks for "(",
- `(?:document\)\.ready\()?` optionally looks for "document).ready(",
- `function` looks for "function",
- `.*?` looks for zero or more anythings non-greedily (normally function would just be followed by `()`, but sometimes named functions are used like `function namedFunc()`),
- `\(\){` looks for "(){",
- `(?:[^{]|{[^]*}\);)+` looks for one or more:

  - `[^{]` looks for a character that is not "{", or:

    - `{` looks for the "{" symbol, followed by
    - `[^]*` looks for zero or more not-nothings (I would use `.*`, but that doesn't match new lines), followed by,
    - `}\);?` looks for "})" with an optional ";",
- `}\);?` looks for "})" with an optional ";",
- `g` is a flag that tells the RegEx engine to search for multiple matches,
- `i` is a flag that tells the RegEx engine to search in a case-insensitive manner

Once you've replaced all matches, you can search for your jQuery commands. The RegEx to do this is much simpler than the previous RegEx.

([RegEx101 Test Case](https://regex101.com/r/dO7qR7/8))

```
/(?:\$|jQuery)[(.].*?[;\n]/gi
```

[image]

Lets break that down:

- `(?:\$|jQuery)` looks for "$" or "jQuery",
- `[(.]` looks for "(" or ".",
- `.*?` looks for zero or more anythings non-greedily,
- `[;\n]` looks for ";" or "\n",
- `g` is a flag that tells the RegEx engine to search for multiple matches,
- `i` is a flag that tells the RegEx engine to search in a case-insensitive manner

Here's an example script that uses these two RegExes to find the commands in the sample input you have provided. Check out the two RegEx101.com test cases I've provided above to see how it will work with some different cases.

```js
var regexes = [
    // https://regex101.com/r/dO7qR7/7 lots more tests here
    /(?:\$|jQuery)\((?:document\)\.ready\()?function.*?\(\){(?:[^{]|{[^]*}\);?)+}\);?/gi,
    // https://regex101.com/r/dO7qR7/8
    /(?:\$|jQuery)[(.].*?[;\n]/gi
], match, matches = [];

var string = [
    "console.log('something');",
    "$('button').trigger('click');",
    "$('div').css('color','red');",
    "console.log('something else');",
    "",
    "$(document).ready(function(){",
    "  // More js here",
    "  $('label').trigger('click');",
    "  $('div.something').text('hello');",
    "  // more js here",
    "});",
    "",
    "$(function(){",
    "  $('.test').append('<div>taco</div>');",
    "});"
].join('\n');

console.log(string);

string = string.replace(regexes[0], '');

console.log(string);

while(match = regexes[1].exec(string)) matches.push(match[0]);

console.log(matches);

// ["$('button').trigger('click');", "$('div').css('color','red');"]
```

Comment: Good idea. Close but the first regex fails if there is a nested function in your jQuery. For example `$.ajax('/url', function(data){ //... });` It see's that `});` and stops there. Using regex to properly match the matching set of brackets is pretty tricky I think.

Comment: @Jake I've updated the answer again, a bunch of limiting to make it safer and just general optimizations, as well as a better explanation.